# How to keep MacBooks keyboard and trackpad functionality when using Windows on Bootcamp?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp, windows, trackpad

Before installing Windows 7, I used to work with Mac OS X on my MacBook Pro. After the installation I noticed that the functionality of the keyboard and trackpad changed. I really want to keep using Windows 7 and the default/old keyboard and trackpad functionality as in Mac OS X.

Comment: What 'functionality' are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Apple's bootcamp drivers? You should be able to go into Control Panel > Bootcamp and change your keyboard/mouse settings there...